# how to support right-click on commits in GitGraph.js

Tags: gitgraph.js

I am using GitGraph.js V2 with react + Typescript. I really need a way to allow users to right click individual commit and then call some callback functions. But don't know how to do that.

I already known how to add a left-click callback on individual commit like this:

```
branchName.commit({
        onClick(commit) {
            .......
        },
      });
```

I hope if someone can give me an example about how to use right-click callback functions on commit.